# Sqlite using Dapper. Error parsing column . Unable to cast object of type System.Int64 to type System.Double

Tags: c#, sqlite, asp.net-core, dapper

I'm using fastcrud and dapper to map my query results to my custom type. I investigated the dapper library and i came to the conclusion that i think it's an issue with the Microsoft.Data.Sqlite package. Not sure if it must be fixed over there but this is the problem.

Before parsing each row from your query result, Dapper uses the GetFieldType method from the SqliteDataReader class to get the correct column types.

Imagine the following table:

```
Id | MinTemp | MaxTemp

1  | 10.5    | 18.2 

2  | 10.6    | 20
```

The `sqlitedatareader.GetFieldType` method will give you the following types:

**System.Int64** for Id and  **System.Double** for both MinTemp and MaxTemp
This seems to be correct but when it's parsing the results the following error occurs on row 2

**Error parsing column 10 (MaxTemp=20 - Int64)
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int64' to type 'System.Double'.**

Due to the [dynamic type system of SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html), it changes the type for MaxTemp on row 2 to System.Int64. But because dapper defined the type for MaxTemp to double it causes the error mentioned above.

If i change my MaxTemp value in my sqlite database to 20.00001 the problem is fixed, but this is not correct.

Used packages:
"**Microsoft.Data.Sqlite**": "1.0.0"

Anyone knows how to solve this problem?

Comment: Running in to a similar problem myself using Microsoft.Data.Sqlite and Dapper. I have a SQLite column defined as Integer but my model is using a bool. For now, I rewrote that specific query to use SqliteConnection, SqliteCommand and SqliteDataReader. Not my favorite but quicker than researching the root issue.

Comment: Looks like its a known issue. https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper/issues/642

Comment: Just saw this same problem in a similar example. Row #2 throws.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This appears to be a bug / flaw in Dapper:

https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper/issues/642

Because SQLite uses value affinity, the value 20 in the second row of the example is treated like an INT. (Even if it was literally inserted as `'20.0'` or `'20.00'` etc.)

Apparently Dapper fails to individually handle the different types which come back for each individual field.

A workaround for this appears to be to use a SQL CAST(). Example:

`SELECT CAST(field123 AS REAL) AS field123 FROM ...`

This appears to get around the bug.

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround in case you are not able to control the query itself, is to change the property type that you are doing the mapping against into "string".

For example, if it fails while trying to parse the column as an int:

```
Id | MyField 
------------
1  | "Hello" 

2  |   999
```

You can modify your MyField property to be a string instead of int and then safely try parse it via code (watch out for perforamnce).

```
class Foo { string MyField } //instead of int MyField
var result = await connection.QueryAsync<Foo>(sql);
```